# Convergence of the sequence $\frac{1}{n^{s+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^s$, $s>-1$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I´d like to determine if this sequence converges and find out what its limit is.

$$c_n=\frac{1}{n^{s+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^s\qquad s>-1$$

Comment: You mean as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Is $*$ hadamard product.?

Comment: no, sry it is just multiplication

Comment: Note that $$c_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^s$$ is a Reimann sum for $\int_0^1 x^s\,dx$.

Comment: $$\int_0^1x^sdx$$

Comment: but why? 0 and 1 come from the upper and lower limit of the fraction?

Comment: thank you very much, solved it

Answer (score 1):

For $s > 0$ :
$$k^s - \int_k^{k+1} x^s dx = \int_k^{k+1} (k^s- x^s) dx = -\int_k^{k+1} \int_k^x s t^{s-1}dt dx = \mathcal{O}(k^{s-1})$$ so that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{s} = \int_1^{n+1} x^s dx+\sum_{k=1}^n (k^{s}-\int_k^{k+1} x^s dx)$$ $$ = \frac{(n+1)^{s+1}-1}{s+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n \mathcal{O}(k^{s-1})= \frac{(n+1)^{s+1}-1}{s+1}+\mathcal{O}(n^s)$$

and for $s > -1$ it is the same with some $\mathcal{O}(1)$ terms